# TChromium(Delphi).How i can close program from TChromium?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, chromium, tchromium

I want to close my delphi program from TChromium component.But i can't do this.I tried to put TPanel above TChromium,but it is wrong,program have an error "Invalid CEF library version".Also i tried to use TImage,but TImage don't stay above TPanel.Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [`OnAddressChange`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefDisplayHandler.html#OnAddressChange) in TChromium.

Add a hyper Link same `<a href="exiting.exit">exit</a>` in your html document after then write `OnAddressChange`:

```
if (url = 'exiting.exit') then
self.close;
```

this a simple fast way.

Comment: Thank you.But this code close document,not delphi program.I need to close Delphi 7 Application.

Comment: I write use this code:

if (url = 'exiting.exit') then
Form1.Close;

Comment: In real, you have used a link target to the `exiting.exit` file which is expected to be stored in the path relative to the current frame's path, so expecting only this target in the `url` is not a right way. Besides, you could rather cancel the navigation in the `OnBeforeBrowse` event without navigating to that target.